# Nginx virtual hosts for multiple LXC containers

Tags: nginx, lxc, virtual-host

I am having the following configuration:

I have 5 LXC containers that are running nginx. On each container there are a couple of virtual hosts set up in nginx. That means for a container I have multiple virtual hosts that are available through port 80.

Each container has an IP like 10.0.3.100, 10.0.3.101, etc.

On the host machine, I also have a nginx server running that has virtual hosts defined.

I would like to know how can I achieve the following: The nginx virtual hosts on the host machine to map on each virtual host on the containers.

For example:
HOST: d1.example.com -> CONTAINER1: d1.example.com
HOST: d2.example.com -> CONTAINER1: d2.example.com
HOST: d3.example.com -> CONTAINER2: d3.example.com

All of them should be available on port 80.

Is there any way to achieve this setup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a reverse-proxy and the directive you are looking for is `proxy_pass`. The host instance of `nginx` will have multiple `server` containers like:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name d1.example.com;
  location / {
    proxy_pass       http://10.0.3.100;
    proxy_set_header Host              $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding   "";
  }
}
```

See the [proxy module documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html) and the [WebSocket documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/websocket.html) (if applicable).